# NameError: uninitialized constant Feed::FeedsPost for many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user model:

```
has_one :feed
```

A feed model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :feeds_posts
has_many :posts, :through => :feeds_posts
```

a post model:

```
belongs_to :user    
has_many :feeds_posts
has_many :feeds, :through => :feeds_posts
```

and a feeds_posts model:

```
belongs_to :feed
belongs_to :post
```

yet when I try to run the following code in the console I get the following failure (after initailizing a user a feed for that user).

```
user.feed.posts
2.1.1 :004 > user.feed.posts
NameError: uninitialized constant Feed::FeedsPost
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add in your class names and and modules to your models too please.

Answer (score 0):

You're naming your models incorrectly; your `FeedsPosts` model must be called `FeedsPost`, and *probably* should simply be called `FeedPost`. It's a *singular* thing, not a collection of things, and Rails depends on this convention.

Rails relies on certain conventions to automatically wire up associations. Your `has_many` only gives Rails this much information: `feeds_posts`. There is nothing there tying it to the actual model in question, so Rails must guess. It does this by assuming you've followed the ingrained conventions, in this case, the association should be plural ("feed_posts") and the model should be singular ("FeedPost"). Because you've named your model `FeedsPosts`, Rails guesses incorrectly, and attempts to access a class called `FeedsPost` which doesn't exist.

You *can* deviate from this convention and continue to use your current name, but you must manually specify the name of the associated model:

```
has_many :feeds_posts, class_name: 'FeedsPosts'
```

Note that this is the *wrong* solution - don't abandon Rails' naming conventions unless you actually have a good reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. Im trying to build an app where users feeds have posts based on certain criteria. Whats the best way to add a some posts to a users feed? i.e. user.feed += posts (I know that doesnt work)

Comment: `user.feeds << posts`

Comment: How would I ensure that it only adds if the records dont already exist? i.e. if I ran "user.feed << Post.all" after the first time it shouldn't add anything.

Comment: @PeterR This is out-of-scope for the comments on this answer. You should ask a new question.